# Calculating the distance between a camera and a target using camera output

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

I have a 640x480 camera that recognizes a rectangle that is 1ftx2ft. Is it possible to calculate the distance between the camera and the rectangle?

**Edit:**

The horizontal angle of view is 54°.

Comment: You will need to know the field of view of the camera and how many pixels wide the rectangle appears in order to calculate the distance away.

Comment: I have these measurements, I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Knowing the field of view you can calculate how far away the rectangle would have to be to completely fill the view with trigonometry.

Answer (score 3):

$$D=\frac{Lw}{2x\tan\frac\alpha2}$$ where $D$ = Distance from Camera, $L$ = length of object (2ft), $w$=width of screen in pixels (640), $x$=width of object on camera in pixels, and $\alpha$ = camera field of view.

Comment: Is it assumed that the rectangle is in the center of the screen or it doesn't matter?

Comment: With a narrow field of view it shouldn't matter where the rectangle is. But it is important that the rectangle is facing flat on to the camera. If you had been using a wide angle lens things might be trickier.